# How to initialise CVPixelBufferRef in Swift

Tags: swift, initialization

We used to initialize CVPixelBufferRef like below.

```
  CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;
```

But in Swift we can not use NULL, so we tried following but of course XCODE want us to have it initalized to use it

```
let pxbuffer: CVPixelBufferRef
```

but how ?

In Obj_C we were creating buffer like this, but as I was trying to explain above when converting to Swift I have been stopped at first line.

```
 CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;

CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, picGenislik,
                    frameHeight, kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, (__bridge         CFDictionaryRef) options,
                    &pxbuffer);
```

Comment: Any reference that takes `NULL` / `nil` is optional variable, please check my answer there I have created an optional `pixelBuffer`

Answer (score 11):

Use [`CVPixelBufferCreate(_:_:_:_:_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CVPixelBufferRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/CVPixelBufferCreate) to create the object

Adding some demo code, hope this helps you. Also do read [Using Legacy C APIs with Swift](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-legacy-c-apis-swift/)

```
var keyCallBack: CFDictionaryKeyCallBacks
var valueCallBacks: CFDictionaryValueCallBacks

var empty: CFDictionaryRef = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, nil, nil, 0, &keyCallBack, &valueCallBacks)

var attributes = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault,
    1,
    &keyCallBack,
    &valueCallBacks);


var iOSurfacePropertiesKey = kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey

withUnsafePointer(&iOSurfacePropertiesKey) { unsafePointer in
    CFDictionarySetValue(attributes, unsafePointer, empty)
}

var width = 10
var height = 12
var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBufferRef? = nil
var status: CVReturn = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, width, height, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, attributes, &pixelBuffer)
```

Comment: I tried CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, width, height, kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, options, pxbuffer) after let pxbuffer: CVPixelBufferRef bu no luck there. It did not like pxbuffer.

Comment: Your latest addition is made me progress a bit more thanks. But, I wonder why it takes that much code just to open a place in memory for pixel calculations. I do not like reading much thats why maybe.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way to do it (Swift 3):

```
var pixelBuffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<CVPixelBuffer?>!
if pixelBuffer == nil {
pixelBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<CVPixelBuffer?>.allocate(capacity: MemoryLayout<CVPixelBuffer?>.size)
}
CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, width, height, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, attributes, pixelBuffer)
```

and then you can access the buffer object like this:

```
pixelBuffer.pointee
```

**EDIT:**

```
    pixelBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<CVPixelBuffer?>.allocate(capacity: MemoryLayout<CVPixelBuffer?>.size)
```

Creates a memory leak if you don't manually deallocate the pointer when you're done with it, to avoid this change your code to the following:

```
var pixelBuffer : CVPixelBuffer? = nil
CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, cgimg.width, cgimg.height, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, nil, &pixelBuffer)
```

Comment: You may want to deallocate the pixelBuffer with   pixelBuffer.deallocate(capacity:  MemoryLayout<CVPixelBuffer?>.size)

Comment: @RocketGarden You are right, thank you for pointing that, I provided a better solution

Answer (score 0):

```
func getCVPixelBuffer(_ image: CGImage) -> CVPixelBuffer? {
    let imageWidth = Int(image.width)
    let imageHeight = Int(image.height)

    let attributes : [NSObject:AnyObject] = [
        kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey : true as AnyObject,
        kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey : true as AnyObject
    ]

    var pxbuffer: CVPixelBuffer? = nil
    CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                        imageWidth,
                        imageHeight,
                        kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB,
                        attributes as CFDictionary?,
                        &pxbuffer)

    if let _pxbuffer = pxbuffer {
        let flags = CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0)
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(_pxbuffer, flags)
        let pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(_pxbuffer)

        let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        let context = CGContext(data: pxdata,
                                width: imageWidth,
                                height: imageHeight,
                                bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(_pxbuffer),
                                space: rgbColorSpace,
                                bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue)

        if let _context = context {
            _context.draw(image, in: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight))
        }
        else {
            CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(_pxbuffer, flags);
            return nil
        }

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(_pxbuffer, flags);
        return _pxbuffer;
    }

    return nil
}
```