# Convert Image to CVPixelBuffer for Machine Learning Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, machine-learning, coreml

I am trying to get Apple's sample Core ML Models that were demoed at the 2017 WWDC to function correctly. I am using the GoogLeNet to try and classify images (see the [Apple Machine Learning Page](https://developer.apple.com/machine-learning/)). The model takes a CVPixelBuffer as an input. I have an image called imageSample.jpg that I'm using for this demo. My code is below:

```
        var sample = UIImage(named: "imageSample")?.cgImage
        let bufferThree = getCVPixelBuffer(sample!)

        let model = GoogLeNetPlaces()
        guard let output = try? model.prediction(input: GoogLeNetPlacesInput.init(sceneImage: bufferThree!)) else {
            fatalError("Unexpected runtime error.")
        }

        print(output.sceneLabel)
```

I am always getting the unexpected runtime error in the output rather than an image classification. My code to convert the image is below:

```
func getCVPixelBuffer(_ image: CGImage) -> CVPixelBuffer? {
        let imageWidth = Int(image.width)
        let imageHeight = Int(image.height)

        let attributes : [NSObject:AnyObject] = [
            kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey : true as AnyObject,
            kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey : true as AnyObject
        ]

        var pxbuffer: CVPixelBuffer? = nil
        CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                            imageWidth,
                            imageHeight,
                            kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB,
                            attributes as CFDictionary?,
                            &pxbuffer)

        if let _pxbuffer = pxbuffer {
            let flags = CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0)
            CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(_pxbuffer, flags)
            let pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(_pxbuffer)

            let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
            let context = CGContext(data: pxdata,
                                    width: imageWidth,
                                    height: imageHeight,
                                    bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                    bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(_pxbuffer),
                                    space: rgbColorSpace,
                                    bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue)

            if let _context = context {
                _context.draw(image, in: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight))
            }
            else {
                CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(_pxbuffer, flags);
                return nil
            }

            CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(_pxbuffer, flags);
            return _pxbuffer;
        }

        return nil
    }
```

I got this code from a previous StackOverflow post (last answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053412/how-to-initialise-cvpixelbufferref-in-swift/42045825#42045825)). I recognize that the code may not be correct, but I have no idea of how to do this myself. I believe that this is the section that contains the error. The model calls for the following type of input: `Image<RGB,224,224>`

Comment: I created a sample project with complete code that can be found here: https://hackernoon.com/swift-tutorial-native-machine-learning-and-machine-vision-in-ios-11-11e1e88aa397

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You don't need to do a bunch of image mangling yourself to use a Core ML model with an image — the new [Vision framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision) can do that for you.

```
import Vision
import CoreML

let model = try VNCoreMLModel(for: MyCoreMLGeneratedModelClass().model)
let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model, completionHandler: myResultsMethod)
let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(url: myImageURL)
handler.perform([request])

func myResultsMethod(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
    guard let results = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation]
        else { fatalError("huh") }
    for classification in results {
        print(classification.identifier, // the scene label
              classification.confidence)
    }

}
```

The [WWDC17 session on Vision](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc17/506) should have a bit more info — it's tomorrow afternoon.

Comment: Works like a charm (with some modifications), thanks. I didn't realize that Vision had a specific type of request for models that output information from an image input. I guess I should've payed closer attention to the documentation...

Comment: For the original question, `VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: CGImage)` is more appropriate.

Comment: @chengsam Not really—the original question starts from a resource on disk. Reading that in as a `UIImage`, converting to `CGImage`, and passing that to Vision loses metadata long the way, but passing the resource URL keeps that metadata available to Vision.

Comment: If the MLModel requires a grayscale image, does the VNImageRequestHandler converts that into grayscale?

Answer (score 15):

You can use a pure CoreML, but you should resize an image to (224,224)

```
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        // Resnet50 expects an image 224 x 224, so we should resize and crop the source image
        let inputImageSize: CGFloat = 224.0
        let minLen = min(image.size.width, image.size.height)
        let resizedImage = image.resize(to: CGSize(width: inputImageSize * image.size.width / minLen, height: inputImageSize * image.size.height / minLen))
        let cropedToSquareImage = resizedImage.cropToSquare()

        guard let pixelBuffer = cropedToSquareImage?.pixelBuffer() else {
            fatalError()
        }
        guard let classifierOutput = try? self.classifier.prediction(image: pixelBuffer) else {
            fatalError()
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.title = classifierOutput.classLabel
        }
    }

// ...

extension UIImage {

    func resize(to newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height), true, 1.0)
        self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
        let resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return resizedImage
    }

    func cropToSquare() -> UIImage? {
        guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else {
            return nil
        }
        var imageHeight = self.size.height
        var imageWidth = self.size.width

        if imageHeight > imageWidth {
            imageHeight = imageWidth
        }
        else {
            imageWidth = imageHeight
        }

        let size = CGSize(width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight)

        let x = ((CGFloat(cgImage.width) - size.width) / 2).rounded()
        let y = ((CGFloat(cgImage.height) - size.height) / 2).rounded()

        let cropRect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: size.height, height: size.width)
        if let croppedCgImage = cgImage.cropping(to: cropRect) {
            return UIImage(cgImage: croppedCgImage, scale: 0, orientation: self.imageOrientation)
        }

        return nil
    }

    func pixelBuffer() -> CVPixelBuffer? {
        let width = self.size.width
        let height = self.size.height
        let attrs = [kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue,
                     kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue] as CFDictionary
        var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
        let status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                         Int(width),
                                         Int(height),
                                         kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB,
                                         attrs,
                                         &pixelBuffer)

        guard let resultPixelBuffer = pixelBuffer, status == kCVReturnSuccess else {
            return nil
        }

        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(resultPixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
        let pixelData = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(resultPixelBuffer)

        let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        guard let context = CGContext(data: pixelData,
                                      width: Int(width),
                                      height: Int(height),
                                      bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                      bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(resultPixelBuffer),
                                      space: rgbColorSpace,
                                      bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue) else {
                                        return nil
        }

        context.translateBy(x: 0, y: height)
        context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

        UIGraphicsPushContext(context)
        self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
        UIGraphicsPopContext()
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(resultPixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

        return resultPixelBuffer
    }
}
```

The expected image size for inputs you can find in the `mimodel` file:
[image]

A demo project that uses both pure CoreML and Vision variants you can find here: https://github.com/handsomecode/iOS11-Demos/tree/coreml_vision/CoreML/CoreMLDemo

Comment: I thought I heard in the Vision session (or maybe one of the other ML sessions) that you don't have to resize the image... Maybe I'm wrong though.

Comment: @pinkeerach : You don't have to resize the image if you use he Vision API (`VNCoreMLRequest`, as in my answer), because Vision handles the image processing part for you. If you use Core ML directly (without Vision), you have to resize and reformat the image (to whatever the particular model you're using wants) and convert it to a `CVPixelBuffer` yourself.

Comment: @mauryat your sample project does nothing. there is not code really.

Comment: @zumzum You can check my sample here https://github.com/handsomecode/iOS11-Demos/tree/coreml_vision , I've implemented both approaches

Comment: @zumzum oops sorry, I think I pushed without committing. I'll remove my link from the comments until I fix that.

Answer (score 2):

If the input is `UIImage`, rather than an URL, and you want to use `VNImageRequestHandler`, you can use `CIImage`.

```
func updateClassifications(for image: UIImage) {

    let orientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation(image.imageOrientation)

    guard let ciImage = CIImage(image: image) else { return }

    let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: ciImage, orientation: orientation)

}
```

From [Classifying Images with Vision and Core ML](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/classifying_images_with_vision_and_core_ml)