# Converting UIImage to MLMultiArray for Keras Model

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, keras, coreml

In Python, I trained an image classification model with keras to receive input as a [224, 224, 3] array and output a prediction (1 or 0). When I load the save the model and load it into xcode, it states that the input has to be in MLMultiArray format.

Is there a way for me to convert a UIImage into MLMultiArray format? Or is there a way for me change my keras model to accept CVPixelBuffer type objects as an input.

Comment: Can you share the code you used to do this?

Answer (score 12):

In your Core ML conversion script you can supply the parameter `image_input_names='data'` where `data` is the name of your input.

Now Core ML will treat this input as an image (`CVPixelBuffer`) instead of a multi-array.

Comment: And once you have your model configured to accept images, you don't need to reformat your images and convert them to CVPixelBuffer manually — the new Vision framework [does that for you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44400741/957768).

Comment: Yes, going through Vision is definitely the easiest way to do things.

Comment: I tried the same. But that didn't fix my issue. Please see this link: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/242517#242517

Answer (score 5):

When you convert the caffe model to `MLModel`, you need to add this line:

```
image_input_names = 'data'
```

Take my own transfer script as an example, the script should be like this:

```
import coremltools
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.caffe.convert(('gender_net.caffemodel', 
'deploy_gender.prototxt'),
image_input_names = 'data',
class_labels = 'genderLabel.txt')
coreml_model.save('GenderMLModel.mlmodel')
```

And then your `MLModel`'s input data will be `CVPixelBufferRef` instead of `MLMultiArray`. Transferring `UIImage` to `CVPixelBufferRef` would be an easy thing.

Comment: Notice that image_input_names='data' only works if your input is really called "data". If you did not rename your input, then it's probably called "input_1" or "input__0".

Answer (score 2):

Did not tried this, but here is how its done for the FOOD101 sample

```
func preprocess(image: UIImage) -> MLMultiArray? {
        let size = CGSize(width: 299, height: 299)


        guard let pixels = image.resize(to: size).pixelData()?.map({ (Double($0) / 255.0 - 0.5) * 2 }) else {
            return nil
        }

        guard let array = try? MLMultiArray(shape: [3, 299, 299], dataType: .double) else {
            return nil
        }

        let r = pixels.enumerated().filter { $0.offset % 4 == 0 }.map { $0.element }
        let g = pixels.enumerated().filter { $0.offset % 4 == 1 }.map { $0.element }
        let b = pixels.enumerated().filter { $0.offset % 4 == 2 }.map { $0.element }

        let combination = r + g + b
        for (index, element) in combination.enumerated() {
            array[index] = NSNumber(value: element)
        }

        return array
    }
```

https://github.com/ph1ps/Food101-CoreML

Comment: Ah, this won‘t work. I‘m the author of that and the only reason why I didn‘t do it like Matthijs is because I needed some preprocessing. The portion where I divide by 255 and substract and so on would be wrong with every other model except mine. To make it work for other remove those calculations from that map.

Comment: What should be done for grayscale images? Also my array shape is [1, 48, 48, 1] and the image size is 48x48