# MLMultiArray from UIImage for sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, coreml, coremltools

I just trained a sklearn model and converted it into CoreML. The problem is, I am using an image as the input to this model. However, what the model is asking for is a `MultiArray` (which is `MLMultiArray`). From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44529869/converting-uiimage-to-mlmultiarray-for-keras-model) I can see that there is a parameter for `coremltools` that can let you specify that the input is an image. But that parameter is for converting a Keras model, and in `sklearn` converting tool this option doesn't exist.

The question is, how do I convert my UIImage to the MLMultiArray required by the model. (or even better, how can I enable image for the model)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your UIImage to byte values and then load those bytes into an MLMultiArray. The question is: what shape is the MLMultiArray and what range should its values be in?

Comment: It is 32x32x3 and it is in RGB layer which has one layer for each.