# convert UIImage to 8-Gray type pixel Buffer

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cvpixelbuffer, coreml

I'm able to convert a `UIImage` to a ARGB `CVPixelBuffer`, but now i'm trying to convert the `UIImage` to a grayscale one buffer.
I thought i had it since the code goes through but the coreML model complains saying:

> "Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=1 "Image is not expected type
>   8-Gray, instead is Unsupported (40)"

Here is the grayscale `CGContext` I have so far:

```
public func pixelBufferGray(width: Int, height: Int) -> CVPixelBuffer? {

        var pixelBuffer : CVPixelBuffer?
        let attributes = [kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue, kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue]

        let status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, Int(width), Int(height), kCVPixelFormatType_8IndexedGray_WhiteIsZero, attributes as CFDictionary, &pixelBuffer)

        guard status == kCVReturnSuccess, let imageBuffer = pixelBuffer else {
            return nil
        }

        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

        let imageData =  CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer)

        guard let context = CGContext(data: imageData, width: Int(width), height:Int(height),
                                      bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer),
                                      space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray(),
                                      bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue) else {
                                        return nil
        }

        context.translateBy(x: 0, y: CGFloat(height))
        context.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1)

        UIGraphicsPushContext(context)
        self.draw(in: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: width, height: height) )
        UIGraphicsPopContext()
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

        return imageBuffer

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: When you're creating a context in this code, have you try to replace the space argument with kCVPixelFormatType_8IndexedGray_WhiteIsZero or kCVPixelFormatType_8Indexed ?

Comment: Thanks for your help, the correct pixel format is kCVPixelFormatType_OneComponent8 for grayscale UIImage

Comment: You could've up vote my comment at least lol

Comment: i just did, cheers!

Comment: Glad you got it working... but you don't need to do your own pixel buffer conversion to feed images into Core ML models: Vision framework does that for you. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/44400741/957768

Comment: Great question @Rickster!! I already know about Vision framework, i've tried it first actually...and believe it or not, the Vision framework did not work with the type of input i had from this custom vision model (VNRequest result was nil). I was able to Using a pixelbuffer and got the expected result though. cheers!

Comment: Error message could be better, agreed.

Answer (score 9):

Even though the image is called grayscale, the correct pixel format is: `kCVPixelFormatType_OneComponent8`

---

Hope this complete code snippet will help someone along:

```
public func pixelBufferGray(width: Int, height: Int) -> CVPixelBuffer? {

        var pixelBuffer : CVPixelBuffer?
        let attributes = [kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue, kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue]

        let status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, Int(width), Int(height), kCVPixelFormatType_OneComponent8, attributes as CFDictionary, &pixelBuffer)

        guard status == kCVReturnSuccess, let imageBuffer = pixelBuffer else {
            return nil
        }

        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

        let imageData =  CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer)

        guard let context = CGContext(data: imageData, width: Int(width), height:Int(height),
                                      bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer),
                                      space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray(),
                                      bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue) else {
                                        return nil
        }

        context.translateBy(x: 0, y: CGFloat(height))
        context.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1)

        UIGraphicsPushContext(context)
        self.draw(in: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: width, height: height) )
        UIGraphicsPopContext()
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

        return imageBuffer

    }
```

Comment: I don't understand how to use this code snippet, where does the context gets the image info from? is this an UIImage extension? please provide an example. thanks